# How do i add SUM with multiple WHERE condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, where-clause

I am currently facing an issue with multiple WHERE condition
I am trying to do this condition.

```
SUM(IF SUM(B.answer) is lesser than 5), 
SUM(IF SUM(B.answer) is between 6-10), 
SUM(IF SUM(B.answer) is between 11-15), 
SUM(IF SUM(B.answer) is greater than 16)
GROUP BY A.schlvl
```

Expecting a result like this:
[image: expected result]

Hope someone get the idea of my explanation

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.schlvl AS school, COUNT(DISTINCT(A.name)) AS NoOfChild, CASE WHEN SUM(B.answer)<5 THEN SUM(B.answer) END FROM child AS A INNER JOIN question AS B ON A.child_id = B.child_id 
WHERE SUM(B.answer) IN (<5,>=6 && <=10,>=11 && <=15,>=16)
GROUP BY A.schlvl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using SUM inside a CASE WHEN, what you can do is SUM the CASE WHEN.

In this case however, when looking at the screenshot of the expected result?
I think it needs COUNT's instead.

Example:

```
SELECT
A.schlvl AS [School Level],
COUNT(DISTINCT(A.name)) AS [Total No. Of Children], 
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN B.sum_answer <= 5 THEN A.name END) AS [le 5],
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN B.sum_answer between 6 and 10 THEN A.name END) AS [6 to 10],
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN B.sum_answer between 11 and 15 THEN A.name END) AS [11 to 15],
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN B.sum_answer >= 16 THEN A.name END) AS [ge 16]
FROM child AS A 
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT child_id, SUM(answer) AS sum_answer
   FROM question
   GROUP BY child_id
) AS B ON A.child_id = B.child_id
GROUP BY A.schlvl
```

Also, if a limit on an aggregation (f.e. SUM, COUNT) is needed, then one would do that in the HAVING clause.

I currently think it's not needed here.
Since getting the ranges of `<=5 or between 6 and 15 or >=16` is hardly a limit. You need them all?

Comment: Thanks for the fast respond, is my `WHERE SUM(B.answer) IN (<5,>=6 && <=10,>=11 && <=15,>=16)` condition correct? The SQL shown me an error on this portion

Comment: It's wrong. You can only use values with an  IN, or a sub-query that returns a list of values.  I'm not sure what you try to limit with that?

Comment: @Yongs Maybe it could help if you added some simplified sample data to your question, and the expected result from that?

Comment: I have just add an example image into the post, am appreciate  for your help!

Comment: appreciate the help! I need to add the B.answer to get the score so.. I tried `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN SUM(B.answer) <5 THEN A.name END) AS '5' ` But it gave me error instead :( . ALMOST THERE!

Comment: @Yongs The problems for someone who tries to solve such puzzles is often because they don't have the real tables & data. And then it becomes a guessing game how that data looks like. But I change it again. It now joins to a sub-query that does the SUM. So it can be used in the outer query.

Comment: Thanks alot! It work! SQL is confusing haha, appreciate that you took your time to help me out! Thanks once again!

Comment: @Yongs I made a small change. `<5` to `<=5`. Because I'm guessing that you wouldn't want to ignore those that are `=5`

Answer (score 0):

if you need  a filter on aggregated  result you must use having and not where 
  and you should use a valid or clause not a in clause with range

```
  SELECT DISTINCT A.schlvl AS school
      , COUNT(DISTINCT(A.name)) AS NoOfChild
      , CASE WHEN SUM(B.answer)<5 THEN SUM(B.answer) END 
  FROM child AS A 
  INNER JOIN question AS B ON A.child_id = B.child_id 
  HAVING SUM(B.answer) IN (<5,>=6 && <=10,>=11 && <=15,>=16)
  HAVING SUM(B.answer) < 5 
          OR (SUM(B.answer) >=6 AND SUM(B.answer) <=10) 
          OR (SUM(B.answer) >=11 AND SUM(B.answer) <=15)
          OR (SUM(B.answer) >=16)
  GROUP BY A.schlvl
```

Comment: I am having issue at `  HAVING SUM(B.answer) IN (<5,>=6 && <=10,>=11 && <=15,>=16)` , i have added an image hoping to clear up the doubt